# Prepositions di/da with cities (origin)

Tags: prepositions

When talking about where I am from (origin of existence) / where I am coming from (origin of movement) and cities, should I use "di" or "da"? For instance:

- Sono da/di Roma.
- Vengo da/di Roma.

Comment: "Sono **di** Roma" and "Vengo **da** Roma".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on which verb you use.
In the first sentence you use the verb "essere", when talking about where you are from, this verb implies a copula such as "originario", in this case you use "di" as specification (not motion).
In the second sentence you use the verb "venire", when talking about where you are from, this verb support the preposition "da" as you in English would say "I came from...", which is a different complement (it implies  motion).

Comment: All perfectly correct, but you might want to add that in old and poetic Italian you may also find _di_ to denote the place a movement strarted from: “Vengo di loco ove tornar disio” (Dante, Inferno), “vengo di lontano” etc.